# How can you run a config script when installing a perl module?

Tags: perl

I've been searching for a couple of hours and I'm coming up empty trying to find a solution. I'm using Dist::Zilla. I have a module that uses a simple config file in `.ini` format located in the module's `share/` directory. When my module is installed, I'd like the install script to prompt the user for configuration options and save the user's options in the config file. Then, using `File::UserConfig`, it will copy the file over to the user's configuration directory where it can be loaded by the module when it runs.

Someone had suggested the [`Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MakeMaker::Custom`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist%3A%3AZilla%3A%3APlugin%3A%3AMakeMaker%3A%3ACustom) module but I know next to nothing about MakeMaker and how I might write a custom one to kick off the configuration script.

I'm surprised I can't find anything that makes this easy to do. Perhaps I'm searching on the wrong keywords?

Comment: Crossposted at https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1227944 - I wonder if using any templating module would be a good approach to pre-fill a config file for the user?

Comment: You want Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MakeMaker::Awesome, not ::Custom. It still generates the normal Makefile.PL but allows you to hook in and add customizations, whereas the latter requires you to write the whole Makefile.PL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had discussed this in IRC, and the gist is:

1. You cannot rely on the installation process allowing any interaction, as a large amount of installations are via cpanm which is non-interactive and hides output from Makefile.PL by default. This is because users don't like having to configure things, and as an example, a Carton deployment is frequently non-interactive by its nature. You can allow configuration via environment variables recognized by your Makefile.PL to get around this.
2. You can document to install using the --interactive option for cpanm in order to respond to prompts in your Makefile.PL, injected into the generated file using the [[MakeMaker::Awesome]](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MakeMaker::Awesome) plugin.
3. You can include a script with the distribution that will set up the configuration so the user can do it themselves separate from the installation.